# require.js when building including one certain module causes script to be lost

Tags: javascript, rjs, requirejs, ace-editor

On my site I use require.js to manage my code, on the main page of my site there is alot of JavaScript with the data-main=MainPage.js. One of the libraries this page uses is the [ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/), this works well when I use require.js to load the files separately however if I try and build this using r.js then all the other files are brought in correctly but the contents of MainPage.js is lost. This is only lost when I require ace/ace, all of the other files like "ace/edit_session" do not cause  me any problem.

this is what I type to compile:

```
node r.js -o name=MainPage out=js/MainPageCompiled.js baseUrl=js optimize=none
```

I am at a loss to why this is, I get no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was using the ace library which had a conflict. It now works.